# How would I run numbers through a list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list `[X, 9, 2, 1, 8, X, 8, 7, 0, 8, 8, 0, 5, 0, 8, 9]` . I want to be able to replace each 'X' string with the numbers 0 - 9 and generate lists of every combination possible with these numbers in place.

I've initializing new lists and appending the items from the old lists in and using if statements to replace 'X' with the new values but haven't had much luck.

The desired output would be to generate lists of every combination with 'X' being replaced with numbers 0-9.

I've already tried converting it into a string then using a for loop to replace X like so:

```
unknown = ['X', 9, 2, 1, 8, 'X', 8, 7, 0, 8, 8, 0, 5, 0, 8, 9]
unknown = ''.join(unknown)
for i in range(10):
    known = unknown.replace('X', str(i))
    x = unknown.replace('X', str(i))
```

but this doesn't give me every combination possible.

Comment: post what you've tried and give us some examples of what it should look like.

Comment: I detect a homework assignment. Especially since this question was just asked earlier today. Did you take a look?

Comment: Where was it asked earlier today?

Comment: well [the question that YOU asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420129/how-to-insert-integers-into-a-list-without-indexing-using-python) is shockingly close =/

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a homework assignment or not. The thing matters is if OP is really tried enough with some code but failed.

Comment: What should happen for multiple X? If there are two Xs should there be 100 combinations or 10 combinations? We need more examples to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah I did ask that question earlier and tried using the .replace method as shown above BUT it only works when there is one unknown number. Using more unknown numbers means it won't generate all list combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it in one line. It's the power of Python:

```
[[x, 9, 2, 1, 8, y, 8, 7, 0, 8, 8, 0, 5, 0, 8, 9] for x in range(10) for y in range(10)]
```

If you want the two `'X'`s with the same value, it's even easier:

```
[[x, 9, 2, 1, 8, x, 8, 7, 0, 8, 8, 0, 5, 0, 8, 9] for x in range(10)]
```

Comment: Your first answer was better.

Comment: Changed back. I thought he only need one variable x

Comment: I've already done 'x' with the same value as I showed in my attempt above but your first example might work (but correct the `xrange` to `range` haha)

Comment: @lan It's b/c you are using Python 3.x. So you need to use `range` instead of `xrange` in Python 2

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend counting how many elements to replace, then using `itertools.product` to generate all the combinations.

```
replacement_count = lst.count('X')

combinations = itertools.product(range(10), repeat=replacement_count)

for combo in combinations:
    combo = iter(combo)
    new_lst = [next(combo) if ch=='X' else ch for ch in lst]
```

This builds the ugliest one-liner I've ever seen:

```
[[next(combo) if ch=='X' else ch for ch in lst] for combo in map(iter, itertools.product(range(10), repeat=lst.count('X')))]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `product` from `itertools`

from itertools import product

```
l = ['X', 9, 2, 1, 8, 'X', 8, 7, 0, 8, 8, 0, 5, 0, 8, 9]
>>> for numPerm in product(range(10), repeat = l.count('X')):
    s = [_ for _ in l]
    for num,index in zip(list(numPerm),[i for i,j in enumerate(l) if j == 'X']):
        s[index] = num
    print(s)
```

this will work for any number of X's so you dont need to keep asking SO to do your homework

Comment: if you used `range(10)` instead of `'1234567890'`, you could avoid the `int` cast later.